# View controller has no initializers

Tags: swift, initialization

```
class ViewController3: UIViewController {

let session = AVCaptureSession()
var camera : AVCaptureDevice?
var cameraPreviewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
var cameraCaptureOutput : AVCapturePhotoOutput
```

I'm very confused because I used this exact same code in a different camera application but for whatever reason I'm getting an error saying that the viewcontroller has no initializers. How can I fix the bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
var cameraCaptureOutput : AVCapturePhotoOutput
```

since is not optional, must be [initialized](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID212):

> Classes and structures must set all of their stored properties to an appropriate initial value by the time an instance of that class or structure is created. Stored properties cannot be left in an indeterminate state.
>
> You can set an initial value for a stored property within an initializer, or by assigning a default property value as part of the property’s definition.

to solve the problem, you might define such property as optional:

```
class ViewController3: UIViewController {
    let session = AVCaptureSession()
    var camera : AVCaptureDevice?
    var cameraPreviewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    var cameraCaptureOutput : AVCapturePhotoOutput?
}
```